# How do I write Grok patterns to parse json data?

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, logstash-grok, grok

I was tasked to filter through data using the elasticsearch-kibana stack. My data comes in JSON format like so,

```
{
"instagram_account": "christywood",
"full_name": "Christy Wood",
"bio": "Dog mom from Houston",
"followers_count": 1000,
"post_count": 1000,
"email": christy@gmail.com,
"updated_at": "2022-07-18 02:06:29.998639"
}
```

However, when I try to import the data into Kibana, I get an error that states my data does not match the default GROK pattern.

I tried writing my own GROK, using the list of acceptable syntaxes [in this repo](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/7.8/libs/grok/src/main/resources/patterns/grok-patterns), but the debugger always parses the key rather than the actual desired value. For instance, the GROK pattern

```
%{USERNAME:instagram_account}
```

returns this undesired data structure

```
{
    "instagram_account": "instagram_account"
}
```

I've tried a couple other syntax options, but it seems that my debugger always grabs the key and not the actual value. No wonder elastic search cannot make sense of my data!

I've searched for examples, but I am unable to find any that use JSON data. To be fair, I'm very unfamiliar with GROK and would like to understand what % , /n , and other delimiters mean within this context.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to import your data into Elasticsearch and where Kibana tells you about grok being wrong? There's no reason to use grok to import JSON data.

Comment: I'm importing data using the "Upload a File" integration, where I get the error "data does not match the grok pattern." I could format my data into csv, but it seems JSON is more robust.

Comment: If you are using Logstash, then you can use [JSON Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) Its pretty easy to use